# Reporting a significant categorical x continuous interaction

Tags: regression, interaction, interpretation, reporting

I am struggling on how to report a significant categorical x continuous interaction, which I found using a negative binomial regression. I have posted the output from STATA below.

So far, I have said something along the lines of, "there was a significant `lang2` by `emotdys3` interaction term at age 3 (B = ***, p = ***), post hoc analysis showed the moderation in the opposite direction to expected. See Figure * for a plot visualizing this effect".

Id like to improve this, and think there may be things to report that I haven't. Can anyone help?

`lang2` = categorical, `emotdys3` = continuous, `sdq_conduct` = outcome, continuous. 
`gendercomp`/`oecd` = covariates. [image]